# Login/Logout user with push notification issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, push-notification

In my app successfully implement push notification related funda and working well.
But facing issue when user successfully logout and login/signup with new user did not get notification.

YES! Here issue is for `DeviceToken`.

- First time I got deviceToken when register push notification.
- Pass this deviceToken to server and and receive push notification.
- Logout this user and register/login through another user
- did not get any token try to `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` but not longer working with iOS 10. and might be not good idea to set like that.

> If we can get new device token then issue will be resoled but might be not possible.

NOTE : By help backend side might be we can solve but suggest me better way. If possible at our side then It's cool.

So what can I do for my second user?

Comment: what you will do while login you will pass devicetoken so at backend webdeveloper will set userid-devicetoken relation so at backend he know on which device token he need to send push for the respective user... When you logout, you will give him userid & devicetoken and webdeveloper will break the realation again...

Comment: @FahimParkar - Yes doing same

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should Write your notification registration code in

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
```

method. Then save that token somewhere e.g. in user defaults

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

    NSString *token; //extract from devToken
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"device_token"];

}
```

Now on successfull login send this token to your backend server. Also on logout send same token to backend in logout request or something and deregister this token from your backend system.

Comment: I tried with same but still not working for other user only first user can get notification.

Answer (score 0):

didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is called once on successful registration of remote notification. You can persist the token as Rahul suggested. But instead of reading this value in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken(), read it in a method that is called after the user logs in. If the value is present, send this token to your server. Your server should remove the token associated with the previous user and assign this token to the new user. From apple server/device perspective, a user is not associated with a device token. So either your api is not getting called after the new user logs in or there is a token mapping issue on your server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing when the time of logout call one web service that will clear your device token for that particular user so when user will register again it will registered with device token and on log out it will clear device token from database